# How to make prefix for title tab

Tags: html, tabs, title, prefix

I'm trying to make a site (for learning purpose) and I want to make prefix for my title tab

For example, let's say that my site name is SZ, and I want every new page I make will have `SZ - something` as the title tab

I think the easiest example is Amazon site, where all the title tab starts with `Amazon.co.jp:something`

oh and even Stack Overflow are using it, but as a suffix as in `something - Stack Overflow`

is there a way to do it without having to add `<title>SZ - something</title>` on every page?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention if you use any frameworks or languages here, but I'll assume you don't. There's no nice way of doing this in plain HTML, typically templating languages take care of this for you.

However, if you've already got a JavaScript file you use, or don't mind adding a JavaScript file, there's a way to do this. This isn't something I would do in a production environment, as it's probably bad for search engine optimisation, but if you're just learning stuff and playing around, this seems entirely reasonable.

`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.title = "SZ - " + document.title;
});`

This means that once the document is fully parsed and ready to go, JavaScript will take the title value as it already exists, and prepend "SZ -" to it, allowing you to set the `<title>My Rad Home Page</title>` on a document and turn it into "SZ - My Rad Home Page", which sounds like what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to do it without having to add `<title>SZ - something</title>` on every page?

There isn't a good way to do that. If you view the source of Amazon or Stackoverflow then you will see the title element has that content.

---

If you are open to bad ways, then you could slap JavaScript onto every page:

```
document.title = "SZ - " + document.title;
```

… but that has all the usual drawbacks of depending on JS.

---

Normally this problem is solved by putting the content in the `<title>` element on every page. As with all such repetitive things, this is best done using a template.

That could be applied server side at run time, or on the development system at build time with a static site generator.